# Mockito - verify that none of the collaborator's methods is called

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I'm a beginner in Mockito.

The SUT, `Foo`, has one collaborator, `Bar`, and in one particular test case, `Foo` should not call any of the methods of `Bar`.

How do I go about verifying it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this:

```
verifyZeroInteractions(bar);
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936301/mockito-how-to-verify-that-a-mock-was-never-invoked).

Comment: This method has been deprecated in favor of verifyNoInteractions.

Comment: newer Mockito versions has verifyNoInteractions() instead