# Mockito - how to verify that a mock was never invoked

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm looking for a way to verify with Mockito, that there wasn't any interaction with a given mock during a test. It's easy to achieve that for a given method with verification mode `never()`, but I haven't found a solution for the complete mock yet.

What I actually want to achieve: verify in tests, that nothing get's printed to the console. The general idea with jUnit goes like that:

```
private PrintStream systemOut;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    // spy on System.out
    systemOut = spy(System.out);
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    verify(systemOut, never());  // <-- that doesn't work, just shows the intention
}
```

A `PrintStream` has tons of methods and I really don't want to verify each and every one with separate verify - and the same for `System.err`...

So I hope, if there's an easy solution, that I can, given that I have a good test coverage, force the software engineers (and myself) to remove their (my) debug code like `System.out.println("Breakpoint#1");` or `e.printStacktrace();` prior to committing changes.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Use this :

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verifyZeroInteractions;

// ...

private PrintStream backup = System.out;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    System.setOut(mock(PrintStream.class));
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    verifyZeroInteractions(System.out);
    System.setOut(backup);
}
```

Comment: Looks like the best I can do for this approach. Thanks! (I've actually hidden most of the logic in a helper class and had to silence the Logger too ;) )

Comment: verifyZeroInteractions has now been deprecated in favour of `org.mockito.Mockito#verifyNoInteractions`

Answer (score 15):

Since the original correct answer, `verifyZeroInteractions` has been deprecated, use `verifyNoInteractions` instead:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class SOExample {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Object mock = mock(Object.class);
        verifyNoInteractions(mock);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
verifyZeroInteractions(systemOut);
```

As noted in comments, this doesn't work with a spy.

For a roughly equivalent but more complete answer, see the answer by gontard to this question.

Comment: (facepalm) - but it doesn't seem to work with spying, I have to mock a PrintStream instead and set it on System...

Comment: Without seeing your code, I would guess that the reason why this fails for your spies is that when you stub your spies, the method call in the stub actually counts as one to be verified.  Three suggestions.  (1) `verifyNoMoreInvocations(ignoreStubs(mockOne, mockTwo));` - this will work like `verifyZeroInteractions`, but ignoring what you've already stubbed.  (2) Are you using the `doReturn/doThrow/doAnswer` methods to set up your stubs?  These generally work better than `when`...`thenReturn/thenThrow/then`, when it comes to dealing with spies.  ...continued

Comment: Suggestion (3) is  to post some more of your code so that the people here can help you better.

Comment: @David, my code example was complete. No more relevant lines. But I'd be looking forward to a working solution with mockito spies. It would be by far more elegant if I could just spy `System.out` instead of temporarily replacing the stream by a mock.

Comment: OK, thanks, I now understand better what you require.  I do have a solution which differs from gontard's and McDowell's - I don't have time to post it now, but I'll do it in a few hours.

Answer (score 5):

You could try a slightly different tack:

```
private PrintStream stdout;

@Before public void before() {
    stdout = System.out;
    OutputStream out = new OutputStream() {
        @Override public void write(int arg0) throws IOException {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not allowed");
        }
    };
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));
}

@After public void after() {
    System.setOut(stdout);
}
```

If you preferred, you could switch the anonymous type for a mock and verify [as Don Roby suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11936364/304).

Comment: Definitely a +1. Unfortunatly I was interested in a solution with Mockito this time therefore I'll accept another answer. Hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 2):

One way of solving this problem is to refactor the class that you're testing, to allow for the injection of a PrintStream that can be used for output.  This will let you unit test it, without relying on the behaviour of the `System` class.  You could use a package-private constructor for this injection, since you'll only ever use it from the corresponding test class.  So it might look something like this.

```
public class MyClass{
    private PrintWriter systemOut;

    public MyClass(){
        this(System.out);
    }

    MyClass(PrintWriter systemOut){
        this.systemOut = systemOut;

        // ...any other initialisation processing that you need to do
    }
}
```

and within the class itself, use the systemOut variable instead of System.out wherever you call the latter.

Now, within the test class, make a mock `PrintStream`, and pass it to the package-private constructor, to get the object that you're going to test.  Now you can run any actions you like from your tests, and use `verify` to check their effects on your mock `PrintStream`.

Comment: Ah, ok, but not exactly what I intended to do: I tried to find a way to test a class without touching it, especially without adding code that is only needed for testing. But on the other hand, if we're willing to prepare the classes under test, then this is really nice approach!