# Unitest Create(Post) method using mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Given a class `SchedulerResource` which has the following `createSchedules` method and a bunch of constants used in the method, how can I use mockito to write a unit-test for the `createSchedules` method?

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<CustomResponse> createScheduler(@Valid @RequestBody SchedulerDTO schedulerDTO) {
    if(schedulerDTO != null)
    {
      schedulerService.saveScheduler(schedulerDTO);
      customResponse.setMessage("Schedule has been created!");
      return new ResponseEntity<>(customResponse ,HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
      customResponse.setMessage("Not Create!");
      return new ResponseEntity<>(customResponse,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND); 
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@Test
public void createScheduler_Success() throws Exception {
    SchedulerDTO scheduler = new SchedulerDTO();
    Long sId = new Long(2);
    scheduler.setSchedulerId(sId);
    scheduler.setLinearChannelId((long)1);
    scheduler.setDurationMs((long) 5000);
    scheduler.setStatus(StatusEnum.NEW);
    scheduler.setStartTime("2018-03-01T05:55:25");
    scheduler.setEndTime("2018-03-01T05:57:25");
when(schedulerService.saveScheduler(scheduler)).thenReturn(scheduler);

    mockMvc.perform(post("/linear/api/1.0/schedules")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(asJsonString(scheduler)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.message", is("Schedule has been created!")));        
}
```

So is ok with :

```
if(schedulerDTO != null)
{
  schedulerService.saveScheduler(schedulerDTO);
  customResponse.setMessage("Schedule has been created!");
  return new ResponseEntity<>(customResponse ,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But what about:

```
else{
  customResponse.setMessage("Not Create!");
  return new ResponseEntity<>(customResponse,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);   
}
```

So, - how can I write for the case where `schedulerDTO == null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: you pass in null, and then you put down *different* specs for your `mockMvc` object, such as `andExpect(status().isNotFound()` (or something alike).

Beyond that, you can use methods like *[verifyZeroInteractions()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936301/mockito-how-to-verify-that-a-mock-was-never-invoked)* to ensure no calls went to that mocked service object for example.

In that sense, it really isn't much different from testing the other case: you step back, and look at all the things that happen in the else branch, and then you think of ways how to observe/verify them.

Comment: And that the response status is NOT_FOUND